# Как запустить RoR веб сервер в production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, веб-сервер

Если запуск сервера с командой rails s - запускается локально.
То для production надо указать внешний IP и порт, при этом открыв их еще для внешней сети?
Я правильно понимаю?

Или есть причины запускать production иначе? Тогда как?

Comment: Для production нужно ставить nginx или что-то подобное